# c# Entity Framework - Generics solution

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

Is there a generics solution for the following code?

```
public static int SaveReorder(IList<int> listItems)
    {
        int result = 0;
        int order = 1;
        Entity1 db = null;

        using (ObjectContext context = new ObjectContext())
        {
            foreach (int id in listItems)
            {
                db = Get(context, id);
                db.Order = order;
                context.SaveChanges();
                order += 1;
            }
            result = 1;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

listItems contains an ordered sequence of identitykeys. 
Entity1 is one of the EntityObjects from our EDM.
Get(...) is a custom method in the same class to get an EntityObject on basis of the current ObjectContext and by Id.

We want a generic solution for this implementation so we can apply this for several EntityObjects, where the property 'Order' is a common property for all the EntityObjects. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options come to mind, as Akash has already suggested:

- Either let the Entities implement an Interface with an 'Order' Property:

  interface IEntityOrder { int Order { get; set; } }

  partial class Entity1 : EntityObject { }

  partial class Entity1 : IEntityOrder { public int Order { get; set; } }
- Or use reflection to set the value of the 'Order' Property (or FieldInfo if it's a field):

  PropertyInfo pi = db.GetType().GetProperty("Order");

  pi.SetValue(db, newValue, null);

Answer (score 1):

No, however in future C# 4.0 using dynamic keywords you can do that.

**Implementing Interface with Order Property**

Currently you can have an interface with order property implemented by each class, I am not sure how to do this in EDM, but it shouldnt be difficult.

We get this kind of problem a lot, thats why C# is coming with dynamic type, we rely on either interfaces or reflection.

Answer (score 0):

OK. Thanx all for your answers.
Here's my solution.

```
public static int SaveReorder<T>(IList<int> listItems) where T : EntityObject
    {
        int result = 0;
        int volgorde = 1;
        T entityObject = null;

        using (vgplannewEntities objectContext = new vgplannewEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (int id in listItems)
                {
                    entityObject = objectContext.GetEntityByKey<T>(id, new String[] { });
                    PropertyInfo pi = entityObject.GetType().GetProperty("Volgorde");
                    pi.SetValue(entityObject, volgorde, null);
                    objectContext.SaveChanges();
                    volgorde += 1;
                }
                result = 1;
            }
            catch
            {
                result = 0;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```